# Use user-environment variable in apache

Tags: svn, apache

I create svn config file, use apache as:

```
<Location /svn/myproject>
SVNPath D:\svnserver\projects\myproject\svn   
AuthzSVNAccessFile D:\svnserver\projects\myproject\conf\access.conf   
Include D:\svnserver\projects\myproject\conf\require_users
</Location>
```

But root-path is repeated so much.

I want to set path as environment variable to simple this config.

```
SetEnvironment PROJECT_PATH D:\svnserver\projects

<Location /svn/myproject>
SVNPath $PROJECT_PATH\myproject\svn   
AuthzSVNAccessFile $PROJECT_PATH\myproject\conf\access.conf   
Include $PROJECT_PATH\myproject\conf\require_users
</Location>
```

Is this possible? How to implement this?

I tried with SetEnv, SetEnvIf of Apache, but couldn't success.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Per the documentation for [SetEnv](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_env.html#setenv):

> Sets an environment variable, which is
>   then passed on to CGI scripts and SSI
>   pages.

So using SetEnv (and SetEnvIf) makes the var available to scripts, but not to apache itself. Unfortunately what you're wanting to do isn't supported.